# Why does not trace() function work in R-Studio?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, trace

I am trying to see the source code of the `ga` function from the `GA` package in R in order to edit it. R-Studio is trying to open a window but, nothing comes up. When I tried for the `mutate` function, it can open a window. Also, when I tried  `trace(ga, edit = TRUE)` in base R, it works. I am using the newest version of R-Studio, too. I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Here is the `sessionInfo` for both base R and R-Studio.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
```

Comment: From the question content it is not possible to come up with a proper and conclusive answer. There is not enough information describing what you're experiencing, such as error-messages, minimal reproducible examples and so forth. Have you tried uninstalling Rstudio completely and reinstalling it? Which system are you on? What is the result of executing `sessionInfo()` from rstudio vs base `R` (maybe something will indicate a discrepancy between the two executions). For such a vague question it seems necessary to do research the problem first and describe the specifics more closely.

Comment: I tried reinstalling R-Studio but in vain. There is not any error. Just, R-Studio is trying to open a window, but it cannot. I have included the `sessionInfo()` in the post.